# Editing custom properties is not working for me, how can I solve the problem of configurated limit in PyCharm?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

The problem I keep getting:

[image: What is the problem I keep getting]

What I tried (1st time):

[image: What I tried (1st time)]

What I tried (2nd time):

[image: What I tried (2nd time)]

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: 1) Have you restarted the IDE after applying that change? 2) Just in case: the correct file to edit is via `Help` menu (this way it will survive product updates and will be carried to next major version).

Comment: 3) If you did all of that and it still does not do what you need .... check this: 3.1) click on "Hector the Inspector" icon in status bar -- try overriding this way (affects current file only) 3.2) Based on your screenshot .. the file is minified (might be just 1 big line) -- IDE is not super good with editing huge lines of text and may disable some stuff in such cases (at very least it was the case in the past). Try applying `Code | Reformat` first (it will make much short lines).

Comment: 3.3) Do not try to use such HUGE number (999999KB in your case). Try a lower value (e.g. 10MB -- 10000).

Comment: @LazyOne thank you so much for your participation in resolving the issue --> but all of the ways you offered are not working with this problem.

Comment: File a support ticket then (can be done from `Help` menu in IDE or via https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731